# SFTP PUT Error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sftp

This is the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Juniper.py", line 66, in <module>
      device_information()
      File "Juniper.py", line 26, in device_information
      device_connection(dev_ip,dev_username,dev_password)
     File "Juniper.py", line 54, in device_connection
      sftp_transfer(r)
    File "Juniper.py", line 61, in sftp_transfer
     c.put("%r" %r)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysftp.py", line 349, in put
      confirm=confirm)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line           
    667, in put    
     **file_size = os.stat(localpath).st_size
     OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "<closed file 'juniper-results20150519-191928.txt', mode 'a' at  
   0x24a0780>"**
```

And the code that produce the error is:

```
def device_connection(dev_ip,dev_username,dev_password):
    file = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    dev = Device(host = dev_ip,user = dev_username, password = dev_password)
    dev.open()
    f = open('show-command.txt')

    for line in iter(f):
        show_command = dev.cli(line)
        r = open("juniper-results" + file + ".txt",'a')
        r.write("***"+ line)
        r.write(show_command)
        r.write('\n')
        r.close()

    sftp_transfer(r)
    return

def sftp_transfer(r):
    c = pysftp.Connection(host = "10.72.129.35",port = 22, username = "Anonymous" , password = "Anonymous" )
    c.put("%r" %r)
    return

device_information()
```

Comment: That traceback sounds to me like you're trying to upload a file but don't have the right path to it, so it can't find the file you are trying to upload.  Try using absolute paths, or make sure you're in the correct directory when you run

Comment: Thanks Eric the file I try to upload is in the same directory that all the other files are in. the first think is it create a file then try to SFTP .it

Comment: Close-voters: how much more clear do you need the question to be?   Isn't it bleedingly obvious that he's asking why he gets this error message?

Answer (score 2):

You are telling sftp to transfer a file descriptor, not the name of the file.

You should change your `sftp_transfer` line to:

```
sftp_transfer("juniper-results" + file + ".txt")
```

so it will use the filename in `pysftp` instead of trying to use the results of `open` stored in `r`

Comment: Not to mention that `r` is closed by the time it is being used, so even if a file  were a valid parameter, it still would not work.

Comment: I am passing it sftp_transfer(r)

Comment: @user3476113 right, but `r` is not the name of the file, it's a closed file descriptor used for reading/writing files.  sftp wants the name of the file to transfer, so you should not pass it `r` you should pass it the filename you want it to transfer, like I tried in my answer